# How to extract specific values from a list in a dict in python?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have downloaded a json file and imported it into python as a dict. Now the dict shows that it only has a len of 2 'id' and 'stats'. I would like to extract the values of 'stats' as a separate dict, so I can manipulate the data further. The manipulation which I want to do further is that I only want the first part of 'stats'. Thus I would only have the stats for the player_fullname = 'Lenny Hampel'.

**My Questions: 
 1. How to get the values of 'stats' into a separate dict ? 
 2. How to only get the values of 'player_fullname': 'Lenny Hampel' ?**

[image]

Comment: What have you tried, and what exactly is the problem with it? Read e.g. https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get your list of dicts with

```
dct_lst = lennymatch1["stats"]
```

And then the player with the name "Lenny Hampel":

```
player = [item for item in dct_lst if item["player_fullname"] == "Lenny Hampel"]
```

All in one go

```
player = [item 
          for item in lennymatch1["stats"] 
          if item["player_fullname"] == "Lenny Hampel"]
```

Answer (score 0):

stats is a list of dicts not a dict. to get the list as a separate variable simply:

```
stats = data['stats']
```

To extract all the names use a list comprehension:

```
names = [d['player_fullname' ] for d in data['stats']]
```

And to get a specific dict in that list use:

```
lennymatch = next(d for d in data if d['player_fullname'] == "Lenny Hampel")
```

This will raise an error if the name isn’t in the list/dicts if you want it to return an empty dict then use the default parameter of next or try/except it depending on your needs